SocketIO Java client not connecting
I am attempting to create a simple connection between a python SocketIO server on repl.it and an Android Java app. When I attempt to connect to the socket nothing is happening.
Client:
Socket socket;
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("https://444ab0e8-2ef4-4b65-b8f8-c1116f6bd6bd-00-2z34bd8dh1mjs.riker.replit.dev:5000/");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

Server:
import eventlet
import socketio

sio = socketio.Server()
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio)
clients = []

@sio.event
def connect(sid):
  clients.append(sid)
  print('connect ', sid)

@sio.event
def disconnect(sid):
  clients.remove(sid)
  print('disconnect ', sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 5000)), app)

When I add socket.connect() or socket.open() under the socket initialization, it connects very briefly but the app crashes immediately. When I leave it out, nothing happens. I've also tried connecting with a python client and it works fine. The problem seems to be solely with the Android app.

Kindly start listening to the error as well because it must be returning some error as it is not able to connect.

throw new RuntimeException(e); - how about printing the stacktrace?

I have fixed the problem. The reason it was crashing on socket.connect() was because I was attempting to Toast within the thread handling the connection event which was crashing the app. I fixed this by simple replacing the Toast with a  Log message
Socket socket;
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("https://444ab0e8-2ef4-4b65-b8f8-c1116f6bd6bd-00-2z34bd8dh1mjs.riker.replit.dev:5000/");
            socket.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("STATE", "e", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("dasoi");
        }

        socket.on("message", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Log.d("STATE", "connected");
            }
        });

